# How to draw a systematic sampling from a square matrix for any wanted number of cells?

Tags: r, math, statistics

I want to write a function that draws a systematic spatial sample of any number of cells `n` from a square grid.

For the example, let's take a matrix of 10 x 10 cells representing the study area :

`m <- matrix(c(1:100), nrow = 10, ncol = 10)`

The conditions of systematic sampling I have to respect are :

- All cells can be part of the sample
- All cells have the same probability of being included in the sample
- The cells selected in the sample must be spread as uniformly as possible across the study area.

To fulfil the first two conditions I see a simple solution : randomly select one cell, and place the other `n - 1` cells uniformly across the study area with a constant spacing between them. By doing this, every cell of the matrix can be included in the sample, and every cell has the same probability of being included.

For example if I want to draw a sample of `n = 4` cells, and the randomly selected cell is `m[2,3]`, then the 3 other cells constituting the sample would be `m[2,8]`, `m[7,3]` and `m[7,8]`, because the most uniform way to spread 4 cells across a 10 x 10 grid is to place them every 5th cell. My sample would then be `c(22, 72, 27, 77)`. This is of course a special case with an easy solution because 4 cells can be arranged as a square of 2 x 2 cells, and the side of the study area divided by 2 gives an integer result.

But how can I do to draw a sample of `n = 6` cells from my 10 x 10 matrix ? The closest way to a square to arrange 6 cells is a 2 x 3 rectangle (this is easy to find for any `n`, it's the factor pair that is the closest to the value of `sqrt(n)`), so I think this is the most uniform way to place the cells, but I can't find any spacing between the cells that respects the other two conditions of systematic sampling. For example if I place the cells every 3rd cell in the x dimension and every 5th in the y dimension, making a 7 x 6 rectangle, then the cells of the 4th and the 7th column have a higher probability of being part of the sample (indicated with darker orange on the picture below, cells containing an x show one realisation of the sample).

[image]

Another problem is if `n` is a prime number, but in this case I'm sure that there is no real solution, so I think the best way to handle it is to select the closest bigger integer (let's call this number x) that can be arranged as a square, draw a sample of size `x`, and then randomly delete `x - n` values from the sample. It's not really a systematic sample, but I believe it's the closest possible to a systematic sample and somehow it seems to respect the conditions. Maybe this way to handle the problem is the best even if `n` is not a prime number : find the number `x` (the closest and superior to `n`) for which it is possible to make a perfect systematic sample, and then randomly delete `x - n` values from this sample.

For a 10 x 10 matrix the possible values of `x` are its factors : `c(1, 2, 5, 10)`, therefore the possible spacings between selected cells are 1 (all cells of the line or column are selected), 2 (every second cell is selected) and 5 (every 5th cell is selected), resulting in the following sample sizes :

- 1 x 1 : 100 selected cells (that's not sampling any more but lets accept this possibility as well)
- 1 x 2 : 50 selected cells
- 2 x 2 : 25 selected cells
- 1 x 5 : 20 selected cells
- 2 x 5 : 10 selected cells
- 5 x 5 : 4 selected cells

If `n = 23`, I select the 2 x 2 spacing, draw a systematic sample of 25 values and randomly delete 2 values from it.

Does anyone see another solution ? And if not would this solution be acceptable from a statistical point of view ?

Comment: how about a Sobol sequence https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobol_sequence ? There are several R packages that implement these ...

Comment: I didn't knew the Sobol sequence, it's a very good idea but it would be very close to [Balanced Acceptance Sampling (BAS)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/biom.12059) which uses the Halton sequence, and my objective is to compare the performance of systematic sampling, BAS and other sampling methods, so I'm going to use a workaround to make something closer to standard systematic sampling instead of using the Sobol sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the workaround I found for the moment. It does not allow exactly to draw a systematic sample for any sample size, but the mean sample size tends towards what's indicated. It's adapted from the function sss.polygon() from package {SDraw}.

```
systematic_sample <- function(pop_counts, nx, ny, sample_size, spacing = c(1,1)) {
  
  # area of the study site
  A <- nx*ny
  
  # compute spacing assuming equal x and y spacing
  delta <- sqrt( A / sample_size )
  
  # adjust for relative spacing
  delta <- spacing * delta / rev(spacing)
  
  # draw the random start point inside a rectangle of dimension delta[1]*delta[2] with the (0,0) point as a corner
  m.x <- runif(n = 1, min = 0, max = delta[1] )
  m.y <- runif(n = 1, min = 0, max = delta[2] )
  
  # get the grid extent
  d <- max(nx,ny)
  
  # get the coordinates of the "rows" and the "columns" of the grid
  seq.x <- seq( 0, d, by = delta[1] ) + m.x
  seq.y <- seq( 0, d, by = delta[2] ) + m.y
  
  # remove points that fall outside the study area
  seq.x <- seq.x[seq.x < nx]
  seq.y <- seq.y[seq.y < ny]
  
  # make the grid
  grd <- expand.grid( x = seq.x, y = seq.y )
  
  # round the grid coordinates to transform them to row and colum indexes
  grd <- ceiling(grd)
  
  # delete doublons
  grd <- unique(grd)
  
  # get the values from the selected cells
  mysample <- pop_counts[cbind(grd$y, grd$x)]
  
  return(mysample)
  
}


# check if all cells have equal chance to be part of the sample
m <- matrix(c(1:100), nrow = 10, ncol = 10)

result_vect <- c()

for (i in 1:10000) {
  sample_vect <- systematic_sample(pop = m, nx = 10, ny = 10, sample_size = 10)
  result_vect <- append(result_vect, sample_vect)
}


length(result_vect)/10000
mean(result_vect)
barplot(result_vect)
# everything seems fine : mean number of cells is 10 and mean value is 50.
```